# HTML Select tag show vertical scroll with 10 option

Tags: jquery, html, css, select, vertical-scroll

I want to make a select box like this

[image]

with 10 select option, when I try to add more than 15 option it show vertical scroll bar,
but not show when it have 10 option.

is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: scroll will appear only when the option is greater than the size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

apply a `size="10"` to your select.

something like:

```
<select size="10">
   // all your options
</select>
```

---

You have to put some style to the label like border, background-image etc.

Something like this to be done:

```
<label id='choose' for='options'>Select options</label>
<br clear='all' />
<select id='options' size="10" style='display:none;'>
    // all the options
</select>
```

then use this jQuery code:

```
$('#choose').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('select').toggle();
});
```

### [Demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZNjz/)

---

Try with this:

```
$('#choose').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).siblings('select').css('width', $(this).outerWidth(true)).toggle();
});

$('#options').change(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var val = this.value || 'Select options';
    $(this).siblings('#choose').text(val);
    $(this).hide();
});
```

---

As you commented:

*when size is greater then 1 of select tag, its not showing blue background in hover, when i add background through css option:hover, its working in FF, but not in chrome and safari.*

so you can mockup with this:

```
$('#options').find('option').on({
    mouseover: function () {
        $('.hover').removeClass('hover');
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    }
});
```

### [Demo with hover class](http://jsfiddle.net/JZNjz/1/).

Comment: I need scroll after clicking in select tag, with size=1

Comment: well then you have to do some customisation. wait i will post something.

Comment: i need like this but with 8-10 option in select jsfiddle.net/Bw7HT

Comment: @RohitK see the added demo.

Comment: its open list on click, but not hide when select 1 option and not change value of label.

Comment: Yes i have not done that, this is just a demo other than this you can do as updated. wait a while..

Comment: Thanks, your code help's me, but i got another issue in it. when size is greater then 1 of select tag, its not showing blue background in hover, when i add background through css option:hover, its working in FF, but not in chrome and safari.

Comment: @RohitK see the updated code, you need to use `.on()` method with use of `mouseover, mouseleave` events.

Answer (score 0):

Size attribute specifies the number of visible options in a drop-down list. If the value of the size attribute is greater than 1, but lower than the total number of options in the list, the browser will add a scroll bar to indicate that there are more options to view.

So use `<select size="10">..</select>`

Comment: I need scroll after clicking in select tag, with size=1

Comment: then u can add attribute of size on event when select is clicked .

Comment: can you give me any example?

Comment: @rohitK ,Hope it helps .