# how to set scroll & caret up and down animation for long dropdown in Angular

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, css

here i have a issue i am generating a dynamic dropdown and trying to set the scroll for dropdown  using **Overflow-y:auto** in some scenario people are suggesting to use size="5" some number but thats works for long selection box not for dropdown.

1.How can I set scroll for dropdown ?
2.How can I set caret up n down for down ?

```
<select>
  <option value="none" disabled >Select Data</option>
  <option *ngFor="let data of dropdownData">{{data.name}}</option>
</select>
```

[image]

stackblitz url :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mirzns

Comment: it may help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119643/html-select-tag-show-vertical-scroll-with-10-option

Comment: @Vega usually i have a dropdown so i thought what if the the items in dropdown increases

Comment: Never mind, I mixed the dropdown and the selection box. But, if you set either size="5" on select or max-height in css and overflow:scroll, you should get a scrolling dropdown https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uny5cq

Comment: ok but i set size ="5" and overflow:scroll also but i didnt get scrollable dropdown

Comment: @Vega https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uny5cq

Comment: @Vega check my update question with image and actually i need like in dropdown i need scroll able but here im getting like selection box in chrome im testing

Comment: @Vega a small help could u once check this issue n let me know what i am missing   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54278724/facing-issue-with-bootstrap-card-unable-to-set-height-equally-in-carousel-using?noredirect=1#comment95380014_54278724

Comment: A drop-down normally opens items if it is having large items then it's don't look good for a normal select drop-down only can't we have scroll and have u checked my other stack link which I posted to you in comment ?

Comment: @Dexter, are you looking for this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahzi76

Comment: @Vega no actually for getting the scroll in select dropdown pple are using ul & li element  and then they are implementing it