# facing issue with bootstrap card unable to set height equally in carousel using bootstrap 4

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, css

here my issue is i unable to set the bootstrap cards in equal height and what is happening in my code is when i try to press prev,next the carousel card in going up an down for further you can check my stack blitz file

requirement is : All cards has to be in same sizes

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" id="datacases">
          <h2 class="info-datacases-h2">datacases</h2>
          <div class="container">

              <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                      <div class="carousel-item active">
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-4">

                                  <div class="card info-datacases-card ">

                                      <img class="card-img-top img-fluid"src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png" alt="Card image cap">
                                      <div class="card-body">
                                          <h5 class="card-title info-datacases-h5 pl-5">slide 1 </h5>
                                          <p class="card-text info-datacases-p text-justify">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 

                                          </p>
                                          <br>
                                          <div align="left" class="pl-0">
                                              <span class="badge badge-data"> sample data</span>
                                          </div>

                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-4">

                                  <div class="card info-datacases-card " >

                                      <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png" alt="Card image cap">
                                      <div class="card-body">
                                          <h5 class="card-title info-datacases-h5 pl-3">Slide 2</h5>
                                          <p class="card-text info-datacases-p  text-justify">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum

                                          </p>
                                          <div align="left" class="pt-3">

                                              <span class="badge badge-data"> slide 2data</span> &nbsp;


                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-4">

                                  <div class="card info-datacases-card ">

                                          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png" alt="Card image cap">


                                      <div class="card-body">
                                          <h5 class="card-title info-datacases-h5 pl-5">Slide 3</h5>
                                          <p class="card-text info-datacases-p text-justify" style="word-spacing: -1.5px">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries

                                          </p>


                                          <div align="left" style="padding: 12px">

                                              <span class="badge badge-data">Slide 3 data</span>

                                          </div>
                                          <p class="cmng" style="text-align:center;background-color: #e5f4f4">data comming soon</p>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="carousel-item">
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-4">

                                  <div class="card info-datacases-card ">

                                      <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png" alt="Card image cap">
                                      <div class="card-body">

                                              <h5 class="card-title info-datacases-h5 pl-3">Slide 4</h5>

                                          <p class="card-text info-datacases-p text-justify">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum

                                          </p>
                                          <div align="left" style="padding: 12px">

                                              <span class="badge badge-data">Slide 4 data</span> &nbsp;
                                              <span class="badge badge-data">Slide 4 info</span>

                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-4">

                                  <div class="card info-datacases-card ">

                                      <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png" alt="Card image cap">
                                      <div class="card-body">
                                          <h5 class="card-title info-datacases-h5" style="padding-left: 6rem">Slide 5</h5>
                                          <p class="card-text info-datacases-p text-justify">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley 
                                          </p>
                                          <div align="left" >

                                              <span class="badge badge-data" >Slide 5 data</span> &nbsp;
                                              <span class="badge badge-data" style="padding-right: 2px">Slide 5 info</span>

                                          </div>
                                          <br>

                                          <p class="cmng" style="text-align: center;background-color: #e5f4f4">data coming soon</p>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-4">
                                  <div class="card info-datacases-card ">

                                      <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png" alt="Card image cap">
                                      <div class="card-body">
                                          <h5 class="card-title info-datacases-h5" style="padding-left: 6rem">Slide 6</h5>
                                          <p class="card-text info-datacases-p text-justify" style="word-spacing: -1.5px">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum

                                          </p>
                                          <div align="left" style="padding: 12px">

                                              <span class="badge badge-data">Slide 6 data</span>

                                          </div>
                                          <br>
                                          <p class="cmng" style="text-align: center;background-color: #e5f4f4">data info coming soon</p>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="carousel-item">
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-4">

                                  <div class="card info-datacases-card ">

                                      <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png" alt="Card image cap">
                                      <div class="card-body">

                                              <h5 class="card-title info-datacases-h5" style="padding-left: 6rem">Slide 7</h5>

                                          <p class="card-text info-datacases-p text-justify" style="word-spacing: -1.5px">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 

                                          </p>
                                          <div align="left" style="padding: 12px">

                                              <span class="badge badge-data">Slide 7 data</span>

                                          </div>
                                          <p class="cmng" style="text-align:center;background-color: #e5f4f4"> data information coming soon</p>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-4">

                                  <div class="card info-datacases-card ">

                                      <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png" alt="Card image cap">
                                      <div class="card-body">
                                          <h5 class="card-title info-datacases-h5" style="padding-left: 6rem">Slide 8</h5>
                                          <p class="card-text info-datacases-p text-justify" style="word-spacing: -1.5px">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
                                          </p>
                                          <div align="left" style="padding: 12px">

                                              <span class="badge badge-data">slide 8 info</span> 

                                          </div>
                                          <p class="cmng" style="text-align: center;background-color: #e5f4f4">data coming soon</p>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-4">
                                  <div class="card info-datacases-card ">

                                      <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png" alt="Card image cap">
                                      <div class="card-body">
                                          <h5 class="card-title info-datacases-h5" style="padding-left: 6rem">Slide 9</h5>
                                          <p class="card-text info-datacases-p text-justify" style="word-spacing: -1.5px">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                          </p>
                                          <div align="left" style="padding: 12px">

                                              <span class="badge badge-data">Slide 9 data</span>

                                          </div>
                                          <p class="cmng" style="text-align: center;background-color: #e5f4f4">data coming soon</p>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                  </div>

                  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                      <!-- <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> -->
                  </a>
                  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <!-- <span class="sr-only">Next</span> -->
                  </a>
              </div>
          </div>

      </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

stack url : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckukyq

Comment: you are not doing it correctly

Comment: i want to help you but if i choose that i make this from scratch because your code is not good

Comment: after check your stackblits i ask to you, write code in proper way or dont make it complex

Comment: @NishargShah  i didn't understand what you are saying and  what wrong with the above if u identified any issue please let me know

Comment: let me try to help you

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ijava now any help?

Comment: @NishargShah it is a multi item slider but the slider is not moving now ?

Comment: I think you don't see right arrow, let ne bright it, because  in my pc its works perfectly